# Убрать часть текста с динамическими данными

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка. Например:

```
Name 1: Text | Name 2: 12 | Name 3: Other text | Name 4: 899 | etc
```

Как правильно, используя имя поля, убрать выбранные участки из этой строки. Чтоб получилось вот так:

```
Name 1: Text | Name 3: Other text | etc
```

Если это статические данные, то можно было бы вот так записать:

```
$array = array(
    '| Name 2: 12 ', 
    '| Name 4: 899 ',
);
$value = str_replace( $array, '', $value );
```

Но, данные постоянно разные для имён. Это может быть `Name 2: 41` и т.д..

Как правильно выбрать участок по имени и удалить его из строки?

Comment: регулярные выражения Name `(2|4):[^\|]+\|`

Comment: принцип удаления то опишите? это четные элементы массива, или это элементы с числовым значением, или что?

Answer (score 0):

Используем функцию [preg_replace](https://phpize.online/popular/preg_replace) с одной строкой или с массивом

```
<?php
$str = 'Name 1: Text | Name 2: 12 | Name 3: Other text | Name 4: 899 | etc';

// убираем одно поле
$field = 'Name 2';

$pattern = "/{$field}:[^\|]+\| /";

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);

print($result);

echo PHP_EOL;


//убираем несколько полей
$fields = ['Name 2', 'Name 4'];

$patterns = array_map(
    fn($field)=>"/{$field}:[^\|]+\| /",
    $fields
);

$result = preg_replace($patterns, '', $str);

print($result);
```

[PHP preg_replace online](https://phpize.online/?phpses=32f37063368ae8f9bec80a6d759ecdfc&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57)